# Best practice for bundling an ".sh" script that launches another online ".sh" script from any linux distro?

Tags: software-distribution

I have created a Java app that depends on Chromium. It needs to be cross platform so all major Linux distros are in play.

I've got a real nice `install-chromium-deps.sh` script that does just that.

But here's the problem, that script changes pretty often due to libraries, chromium updates, etc. So, my `install-chromium-deps.sh` installer script really needs to fetch another `.sh` script from a trusted online location and run that instead. That way when changes happen, I can update my online version of the installer script and not have to send my customers an updated `.sh` file each time every little change happens.

Is there some industry standard way to accomplish this across all Linux platforms?

Comment: Create a proper package with dependencies properly defined and let the distributions package manager deal with dependency handling

Comment: that sounds like the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to post your code and a set of well tested instructions and requirements and let the end user deal with it.

The most correct way is to provide a package with properly configured dependencies, and let the distribution's package management system deal with it all.  Of course, this means you'll need to determine what and how across however many distributions you support, and your work load will grow exponentially for every distro you do support, and be multiplied by how often you update the core software you are trying to distribute.

I would take a look at your build and install process and see how much of it can be eliminated.  The easier it is to package, the more likely someone will want to maintain a package for Debian or RedHat or Gentoo or whatever other distro.